# Save pdf document with name based on text in the document

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe

I have pdf files to be renamed. The format of each of the pdf files is exactly the same.

In the pdf file, there is a string of text that says "Your location number is: 0001".

Is there VBA to scan each of these files and then save the document according to the location number. In this instance, the document should be saved as: 0001.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to look at [adobe-acrobat-and-vba-an-introduction](http://www.khk.net/wordpress/2009/03/04/adobe-acrobat-and-vba-an-introduction/)

This article refers to [Acrobat Reader Interapplication Communication](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_developer_guide.pdf) and its [API reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf)

These documents explain you how to launch, load and navigate through a PDF document using the COM objects of Acrobat Reader application.

```
Dim app as Object, avdoc as Object, pageview as Object
Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set avdoc = app.GetActiveDoc
Set pageview = avdoc.GetAVPageView
'...
```

I hope this answer your question.